# Buy a YouTube video for someone else (i.e. as a gift)?

Tags: youtube, google-account, google-play

YouTube make it easy and straight forward to buy content *for yourself*. But suppose you want to buy some YouTube paid content for someone else.

Is it possible, and if so, how?

#### What I know so far

I googled but could only find [how to gift a video on Vimeo platform](https://support.vhx.tv/article/70-buy-a-gift) (i.e. not YouTube)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [Google Play gift cards](https://play.google.com/about/giftcards/)

### What happens when you buy a Google Play gift card

> *...the user purchasing the gift must designate a single recipient using an individual email address...*

**The recipient can be the person you want to make the gift to.**

After you buy the gift card, a message is sent to the email you chose during your buy.
When the recipient of the email **[redeems the gift card](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7259382)**, the gift card amount gets added to his/her **[Google Play balance](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3423011)**.

**What you can buy with your Google Play balance**
That [depends on your country](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6080850).

**ATTENTION**:
To use a gift card or promotional code, **the country of your Google Play Account must match the country where the gift card or promotional code is offered**.

**Make sure you carefully read all of the *[GOOGLE PLAY GIFTS TERMS OF SERVICE](https://play.google.com/intl/ALL_uk/about/gift-terms/)***

> Google Play gifts are valid only for users who are residents of the countries listed on the Help Center. For such offers, **the user purchasing the gift must designate a single recipient using an individual email address** (not a group email alias). **Such gifts can only be purchased and redeemed by users in the same country**. In order to redeem the gift, the recipient of the gift must have a valid Google account and valid gift code. If the user who purchased the gift cancels their purchase prior to the recipient redeeming the gift, the recipient will no longer be able to redeem the gifted content. A copy of the gift email is sent to the purchaser. If the gift recipient wants to reject the gift, the recipient should inform the user who purchased the gift and the purchaser will be able to send the same gift to another user. **Anyone with access to the gift email can use it**. Google is not responsible for gifts that are redeemed without the purchaser’s or recipient’s permission.

There is plenty of information about the gift cards under [Google Play gift cards, promotional codes, & balance](https://support.google.com/googleplay/topic/3421691)

Since [December 2019](https://youtube.googleblog.com/2019/12/youtube-gift-codes-are-now-available-on.html) you can even buy gift codes from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081ZVR4R9).

***How to gift the card from Amazon***

- Go to Amazon to get to the purchase page.
- Choose a design and your desired amount.
- Enter the recipient’s email address and a message.
- Pick your delivery date and select purchase.

Comment: Have you tried the given answer? Did it work for you? As mentioned, key points are the Terms of Service, what can the balance be used for and the countries of both accounts.

Comment: _"stevec wants to draw more attention to this question"_. You got mine. I can see you are logged-in and have been making rounds in stackoverflow. So you have definitely seen my answer. I wonder why 6 days later there is no reaction to it. In any case, I would love to know wether it worked for you or not.

Comment: hi thanks for the help. Gift cards are not good for a few reasons. I need either a) user logs in to get notified I've bought them a vid and it's available, or b) I send them a link to the paid-for vid and they can watch it. Gift cards have two flaws: i) they involve too much messing around on the recipient side, and ii) the gift giver cannot be sure that they've spent the gift card on the designated item and nothing else

Comment: upvote for the idea though

Comment: Check out the vimeo example in the question, in about 1 min, I can purchase and send a recipient the paid-for video. They don't go searching for it, it's right in their inbox. No fussing with currencies, gift cards, gift card terms and conditions, minimum spend, or additional emails. Vimeo make it very simple and easy, just like if you were to buy a physical copy of a dvd and hand it to someone. I need to find an equivalent for youtube

Comment: Awarding the bounty since you helped

Comment: _"Check out the vimeo example... I need to find an equivalent for youtube"_. I am afraid there isn't. Adding to the flaws you mention the _"Such gifts can only be purchased and redeemed by users in the same country"_ part. Couple months ago a friend was _"stuck"_ with the present  bought for someone. We ended up downloading it and re-uploading it as a private unlisted video in YouTube and have the link emailed so they could watch it. I hope they eventually make it user friendly. Anyway. Thanks for the bounty.